# Calling Dynamic HTML generating function on PageLoad with UpdatePanels, Slidorion, and Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am calling a function **GenerateControls()** which generates dynamic HTML inside a panel of asp.net. I have used `TableCell` and `TableRow` control classes for generating the dynamic HTML. Now this panel is inside one of the slider divs of [slidorion](http://slidorion.com/) control. Now when I call the function on page load I am getting an `jquery` error "Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'". After some debugging, I found that every time the function **GenerateControls()** is invoked on page load, the jquery and JavaScript files are not loaded properly and the page gets distorted. The asp panel is inside an `asp:UpdatePanel`. There is another button control that invokes the function on click event and it is registered as asynchronous postback trigger for the mentioned update panel. In this scenario, the function **GenerateControls()** executes properly and the controls are rendered as desired. Now I am stuck in a scenario where I have to call the function on Page Load (to load already existing data that is displayed in the dynamic controls) but somehow want to render the control after all the script files are added. Kindly suggest. And thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found the error! Actually along with the Dynamic controls, I was also creating validation controls from code behind. So I set the property, `EnableClientScript = false;` and it worked!